# bash getopts can't assign value to variable

Tags: bash

I'm setting variable `dag='false'` at beginning, if `-d` argument is provided then `getopts` set `dag='true'`, but it still is false. Here is the my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

dag='false'
replacement=''

print_usage() {
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` [-h] [-d] [-r]"
  echo "This script find all texts that match the given text pattern in the given repository,"
  echo "then delete these texts or replace them with new text if -r is given, reformat each files."
  echo "Optionally, it can generate DAG which can be used as test plan."
  echo
  echo "Syntax: remove_optin_filters.sh <path to repository> <regex-style match pattern> -r(optional) <replacement> -d(optional, to generate DAG)"
  echo
  echo "positional arguments:"
  echo "path_to_repository          path to the desired directory"
  echo "match_pattern               regex-style pattern to match text"
  echo
  echo "options:"
  echo "-h                          Print this Help"
  echo "-d                          Generate DAG to all files changed and save them to pastry"
  echo "-r                          replace text with provided text"
  exit 0
}

while getopts 'dhr:' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    d) dag='true' ;;
    h) print_usage ;;
    r) replacement="${OPTARG}" ;;
    \?) echo "Incorrect usage";;
  esac
done

echo $dag

# first argument is the repository path
repo=./$1

# second argument is the regex pattern to match text
pattern=$2

# find all files+patterns in given repository that match the given pattern,
# and save to sg file. (sg is temp file and will be removed at the end)
find $repo -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -iH "$pattern" {} \; > sg

# retrieve all the file pathes. Dedup, sort and remove the trailing colon
# save them to sg_unique file. (sg_unique is temp file and will be removed at the end)
cat sg | awk '{ print $1; }' | uniq | sort > sg_unique
sed -i "s/:$//" sg_unique

# remove or replace the texts from all files
if [ "$replacement" == "" ]
then
  for l in $(cat sg_unique); do sed -i "s/$pattern//ig" $l; done
else
  for l in $(cat sg_unique); do sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/ig" $l; done
fi

# format all files
for l in $(cat sg_unique); do arc dsfmt $l; done

# option(flag = -d): generate DAG for all files and save them to pastry
if [ "$dag" == "true" ];
then
  echo "Generate DAG..."
   for l in $(cat sg_unique); do echo "$l"; ./status --tree -q $l; echo ""; done |& pastry
else
  echo "No DAG verified"
fi

# clean out temp files
rm sg
rm sg_unique
```

Here is the command:

```
./remove_optin_filters.sh <repository> "AND COALESCE(privacy_optin_flag, 'ON') = 'ON'\|AND latest_privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'\|AND privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'" -d
```

Result:

```
false
No DAG verified
```

Comment: See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02 -- in standards-compliant UNIX commands, options go **before** positional arguments. GNU tools have relaxed that, but it's not a standard convention, and traditional getopts doesn't support it.

Comment: Also, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and correct string comparison is `[ "$foo" = "bar" ]`, not `[ "$foo" == bar ]` -- see the [POSIX `test` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html): the only standardized string comparison operator is a single `=`; `==` is an extension, and baseline-POSIX shells don't support it. It might be good to run your code as a whole through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it identifies.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: After you process the options (after the `while` loop), you need to shift the options out of the positional parameters: `shift $((OPTIND - 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
while getopts 'dhr:' f
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

```
./testgetopts.sh -d -h x -r -d
```

→

```
d
h
```

In other words, getopts returns false (non-0 exit code) as soon as it encounters something else.

Your `-d` flag is after many things that are not what `getopts` is looking for

Try with

```bash
./remove_optin_filters.sh -d <repository> "AND COALESCE(privacy_optin_flag, 'ON') = 'ON'\|AND latest_privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'\|AND privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'"
```

Or, in the scrpit, read the directory first, then `shift`, then copy the filter, then `shift`, and then `getopts`

```bash
mydir="$1"
myfilter="$2"
shift 2

while getopts 'dhr:' f
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

This time

```
./trygetopts foo bar -d
```

shows the expected `d`

Comment: Where does the OP show a use of `-d` in their sample command at all? I don't see them passing it in the first place (why they'd ask a question about getopts when they aren't _using_ getopts...)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy At the very end.

Comment: BTW, might use `echo "$f"` to be demonstrating good practices (see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))

Comment: I don't get what "help" message you are referring to. But for me their actual usage example is `./remove_optin_filters.sh <repository> "AND COALESCE(privacy_optin_flag, 'ON') = 'ON'\|AND latest_privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'\|AND privacy_optin_flag = 'ON'" -d` and I see a `-d` at the very end. I feel that we are not talking about the same thing. But I am pretty sure that `-d` is the reason why OP expected to have the `getopts` reading `d` flag, and therefore that `dag` variable to change.

Comment: By "help" I was referring to the `Usage:` string in the `print_usage` function. I was having trouble scrolling over far enough to see the `-d` -- with my browser's window size clicking to scroll right one window-length was precisely cutting it off.

Comment: Note: duly noted, and edited accordingly for the `"$f"`. I tend to be a bit "quick" about what the question is not about when responding. But I reckon that is a bad habit, especially when it cost only two bytes to avoid spreading bad practices.

Comment: the -d can be placed anywhere ideally, but I can enforce it be placed after the 1st and 2nd argument. but the 2nd option doesn't work for me